# Append DOM elements names from loop variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, webkit

This code not working and I have no idea why ;/

```
<div class="pet"> some info </div>

for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    $('.pet').append( '<p id="xxx'+ i +'">'+ i +'</p>');

    //other code...

    for (var x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
        $('"#xxx'+ i +'"').append('<p>'+ x +'</p>');
    }
}
```

but when I for example make in second loop:

```
$('#xxx20').append('<p>'+ x +'</p>');
```

it adds everything after 21 element

I am using webkit+nodejs

Comment: what do u want to do?

Comment: I would like to append some things to div with loop within loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you shouldn't be using `<p>` tags inside of `<p>` tags because it's a block level element. Then you have some minor errors in your code

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    $('.pet').append('<p id="xxx'+ i +'">'+ i +'</p>');

    //other code...

    for (var x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
        $('#xxx'+ i).append('<i>'+ x +'</i>');
    }
}
```

You can see that in your second loop you a comma instead of a semicolon and your selector was too "quoted".

Comment: Yea this comma was mistake when prescribing, still dunno how to fix it

Comment: for more than an hour i am traying to quote good this selector, thats is a problem I think

Comment: sure, sorry. I forgot about it.